# mysql information_schema columns insert in other table with modifications

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following select :

```
SELECT 
    col.table_name, col.column_name, col.ordinal_position, col.is_nullable, col.data_type
from 
    information_schema.COLUMNS col 
where 
    col.table_schema = 'i2cwac' and
    col.column_name not in ('id','modifiedAt','modifiedBy','createdAt','createdBy') and
    col.table_name = 'users'
;
```

and I want to insert all of this in a table called 'table'(I have this table with all columns returned by select) which has a new column named 'enabled'(BIT(1)) and I also want to change what it's inserting in column 'is_nullable'.

Above select returns 'YES' or 'NO' in 'is_nullable' column but in table 'table' in column 'enabled' I need 1 or 0.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [case expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) in order to map yes/no into 1/0.

```
insert into table (columns_names_here)
select    
   col.table_name, .... 
   case when col.is_nullable = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end as enabled, 
   col.data_type
from 
 ....
```